# Python two variables are the same but python doesnt think that they are

Tags: python

I am making a program which has a login; it checks the input against the user's input. However, it won't accept that they have entered the correct password, even when it is correct:

```
for i in range(5):
    existingUsername = input("What is your user name?")
    if existingUsername in open('logins.txt').read():
        with open("logins.txt", "r") as myFile:
            for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
                if existingUsername in line:
                    passwordLine = num + 1
                    passwordAttempt = input(str("What is your password?"))
                    passwordText = linecache.getline("logins.txt", passwordLine)
                    if passwordAttempt == passwordText:
                        print("That is correct")
                        quizSelection()
                        break
                    else:
                        print("That doesn't seem to match. Please try again")
```

The text file it references only has Har16 and Google in it, on separate lines with Har16 at the top

Comment: are you sure the passwordText doesn't have any spaces or other characters with it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Try printing `repr(passwordAttempt)` and `repr(passwordText`. They won't be the same - computers do not lie.

Comment: Please demonstrate the problem explicitly.  Among other things, you need to display the strings you're comparing, with some way to distinguish white space: leading/trailing blanks, line feeds, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `passwordText = linecache.getline("logins.txt", passwordLine)`, if your file has multiple lines, it may return the string with `\n` at the end.